# vagrant-vbguest plugin installation failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, vagrant-plugin

I'm trying to setup a vagrant system for rails development.

My vagrant version is Vagrant 1.4.2 and I have installed both the plugins vagrant-librarian-chef (0.1.4) and vagrant-vbguest (0.10.0).

But when I do `vagrant up` I get the following error.

> The plugin "vagrant-vbguest" could not be found. Please make sure that it is
>   properly installed via `vagrant plugin`. Note that plugins made for
>   Vagrant 1.0.x are not compatible with 1.1+ and this error will likely
>   continue to show when you use `plugin install` with a 1.0.x plugin.
>   Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
>   There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
>   the following errors and try again:
>
> vm:
>   * The box 'base' could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

You can uncheck the vbguest in the vagrant file and try again

Answer (score 0):

I have uninstalled vagrant-vbguest and installed vagrant-vbguest.

vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-vbguest
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest --plugin-version 0.21